# Show that there's no solution to $u''e^{-u'}=2u$ satisfying given boundary conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u\in C^2([0,1])$ satisfies
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
-u''e^{-u'}+2u&=0\ \text{in}\ [0,1] \\
u(0)&=0\\u(1)&=1
\end{aligned}               
\right.$$ 
Show that there is no such $u$ satisfying the equation or prove otherwise

I have figured out that both $u,u'$ and $u''$ are strictly increasing and $u>0\ \text{in}\ (0,1)$.

All the best, thanks.

Comment: Multiply with $u'$ and integrate to get
$$
C=-(u'-1)e^{u'}+u^2=-(u_0'-1)e^{u_0'}+u_0^2=-(u_1'-1)e^{u_1'}+u_1^2
$$
and with the Lambert-W function 
$$
u'=1+W_k(e^{-1}(u^2-C)), ~~k=0,-1.
$$

Comment: Thanks LutzL, I have worked it out.

Comment: With the corrected sign distribution the first integral is $$C=(u'+1)e^{-u'}+u^2$$ so that $u'=-1+W_k(e^{-1}(u^2-C))$. As $C<1$ and $u'=1$ somewhere inside the interval, all of the solution is on the $k=0$ branch. -- Could you give a hint what approach you used to solve this? Numerically I get that the IVP with $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=v$ has a maximum close to $v=8$ with value about $0.936$ at $u(1)$, that is, the second boundary condition is indeed not satisfiable.

Comment: Exactly yes,such sol. to this eq. with the given boundary condition does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the ODE with $u'$ and integrate to obtain the first integral
$$
C=(1+v)e^{-v}+u^2\approx 1-\frac{v^2}2+u^2.
$$
The stationary solution is $u=0$, close to the point $(u,v)=(0,0)$ the first integral looks like $1-\frac12v^2+u^2$ which indicates a hyperbolic or saddle point.
The level corresponding to that point is $C=1$ and the curves
$$
u=\pm\sqrt{1-(1+v)e^{-v}}=\pm\sqrt{\tfrac12v^2-\tfrac12v^3-(1+v)(e^{-v}-1+v-\tfrac12v^2)}
$$
divide the plane in four parts,

[image: phase portrait]
*$(u,v)$ phase portrait - solutions move from red to blue, in green the curves starting or ending at the saddle point*

One can see and then confirm that it is impossible to move from $u=0$ to $u=1$, as the ray $u=1,~ v=0$ is separated from the positive $v$ axis.

Moreover, the points reached after time one are even closer to zero, they never reach $u=0.3$.
[image: end point versus initial velocity]
*diagram of $u(1)$ in dependence of $u'(0)=v(0)$*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, and there is a theoretical proof maybe I can post later. Thanks again!

Comment: As your idea,  multiply the eq. with $u′$ to get $$\int_0^xu'u''e^{-u'}dx=2\int_0^xuu'dx,$$ or equivalently $$u^2(x)=\int_0^xu'e^{-u'}du'<\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx=1,$$ which is contradictory to $u(1)=1$.

Comment: The last strict inequality is deduced by the fact that $u'>0$ and $u''>0$.